# rsh -l login host ls connection refused (Unix Solaris 9)

Tags: solaris, rsh

I currently have an issue when login to a remote server. 
I can perfectly log in with rsh -l login host. or with rlogin.

However, when trying to use an ls command, the server refuse the connection. 
I do not have the root account.

The content of the .rhosts is set with the server name and login from where I perform the connection.

content of /etc/pam.conf

```
# Authentication management
#
# login service (explicit because of pam_dial_auth)
#
login   auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
login   auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
login   auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
login   auth required           pam_unix_auth.so.1
login   auth required           pam_dial_auth.so.1
#
# rlogin service (explicit because of pam_rhost_auth)
#
rlogin  auth sufficient         pam_rhosts_auth.so.1
rlogin  auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
rlogin  auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
rlogin  auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
rlogin  auth required           pam_unix_auth.so.1
```

content of /etc/hosts.deny

```
sshd : ALL
```

Do you have any suggestion ? 
Thank you.

Comment: This is really a sysadmin problem and should be on serverfault.